# How to compile QGIS 2.4.0 on Ubuntu Precise 12.04

Tags: qgis, error, compilation

Been trying to compile this for a couple of hours, using this download:

http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-latest.tar.bz2

and these instructions:

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html#toc3.

I have problems with `libproj-dev` - I can't install it, get this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   libproj-dev : Depends: libproj0 (= 4.8.0-3~precise2) but 4.8.0-3~precise5 is to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I installed the headers by hand - compiler accepted them - and have tried to link in /usr/lib/libproj.so as `PROJ_LIBRARY` in ccmake. The compiler doesn't like this, I get:

> make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libproj.so', needed by`output/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.4.0'.  Stop.
>   make[1]: *** [src/core/CMakeFiles/qgis_core.dir/all] Error 2

I also get 'Could not find GRASS' a little earlier in the build - don't know if this is significant.

I'm a bit confused, `libproj.so` shouldn't be a target? Anyway, can anyone help? My ppa is the ubuntugis stable one - maybe I need unstable?

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to compile from source rather than just installing 2.4 from ubuntugis-unstable/qgis.org?

Comment: Because I want to develop a stripped-down version for fieldwork - that will eventually work on Android. thought I'd best start by learning how to compile QGIS?